# Add AudioKit to AVCaptureSession as audio inputs

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, avcapturesession, audiokit

Is there any possibility to add AudioKit as AVCaptureSession inputs.

I am going to use AudioKit Microphone feature on recording video.

```
        let audioInputDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio)!
        let session = self.previewLiveCamera.cameraLayer!.session!


        //Here we Add Audio Input
        do {
            audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioInputDevice)
            session.addInput(audioInput!)
        } catch {
            print("failed to add audio input")
        }
```

Currently, I used AVCaptureDeviceInput but it recorded microphone & internal video sound.

I really want to record only microphone sound, not video sound playing on phone. Thanks